# Calculated column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I created a data_frame using the following code:

```
data_series = {}
while not q.empty():
    (name, data_dict) = q.get()
    data_series[name] = pd.Series(data_dict)`
data_frame = pd.DataFrame(data_series)

#data_dict is of the format { MD5: [time_as_float1, time_as_float2] }
#I have multiple data_dicts stored in a queue (created by multiple worker threads)
```

I would like to basically be able to achieve the following:
1. For each MD5, output how much time `flog`, `hlog` and `slog` took. (By subtracting corresponding time_as_float2 and time_as_float1)
2. For each of `hlog`, `flog` .., show first time they saw an MD5 (smallest time_as_float1) and last time they saw an MD5 (max(time_as_float2)

`data_frame:
Index: 395 entries, 0037B4F499705D725C2B3B00956B574E to FF11433CC64568110D3AD46037290725
Data columns (total 3 columns):
flog    220  non-null values
hlog    175  non-null values
slog    20  non-null values
dtypes: object(3)`


`(Pdb) data_frame['hlog']
0037B4F499705D725C2B3B00956B574E     [1401808481.57, 1401808481.7]
016E73F1038CE46AF4A619453AC7DE70    [1401808491.38, 1401808491.51]
0250F3B15665E8B00F7D58CCA8C2C8F4                               NaN
0260FA375596B150DF8B4D7E3CA2D934                               NaN
03173B333E22CE63F6485AC87D616878    [1401808482.36, 1401808482.49]`

I'm not even sure if my way of constructing the data_frame is correct, cuz it feels like my requirements are so simple, they'd be supported by default.

Comment: Can you give a sample of `q`? 2 lines would suffice, just to make reproduction of your data sets easier

Comment: q is a `Queue.Queue` object that contains tuples of (name, data_dict).. name is str and data_dict is in the question already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, your way of constructing the data frame is not really good. Try to make use of pandas strong interaction with numpy.

I create the dataframe first (for all indices, you should know how many rows you will have ex-ante for better performance) and then populate by row. I cannot improve this part since I don't have python 3 and `queue`.

```
# first initialize dataframe
data_frame = pd.DataFrame(columns=['type', 'hash', 't0', 't1'], index=np.arange(10))

# this is now what would have to be inside the queue loop
data_dict = {'type': name, 'hash':md5hash,
             't0': times[0], 't1': times[1]}
name = "hlog"

data_series = pd.Series(data_dict)

data_frame.loc[0] = data_series
data_series[['t0', 't1']] += 0.5 # now I just quickly "fake" an additional loop to create more data
data_frame.loc[1] = data_series
```

This is now how my data set looks:

```
   type hash   t0   t1
0  hlog  MD5  0.1  0.2
1  hlog  MD5  0.6  0.7
2   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
(...)
```

So now, with having separate columns for `t0` and `t1`, your first question becomes very easy:

```
data_frame['time-it-took'] = data_frame['t1'] - data_frame['t0']
```

The second one has also been answered quite often here at SO: It is a typical groupby-apply combination you can find a lot information on in the documentation:
    # set as index: type
    data_frame.set_index(['type'], inplace=True)
    # by type: group up, and set as value the minimum `to`
    data_frame['first-time'] = data_frame.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x['t0'].min())

This is now how my data looks (with the index still set to be the hash type):

```
     hash   t0   t1 time-it-took  first-time
type                                        
hlog  MD5  0.1  0.2          0.1         0.1
hlog  MD5  0.6  0.7          0.1         0.1
NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN          NaN         NaN
```

Once you understood what happened here, I'm sure you can apply this to find the maximum of 't1'.

Again, they key was to set up the data frame properly, which is something you should spend more time on doing. Try thinking about the ways your data would be structured most logically.